# What is an acceptable receive rate for a client?

Tags: unity, networking

I've noticed that syncing a transform( in Unity, so a Vector3, and a Quaternion ) ends up being close to 1000 byes per second received on a client( send rate of 20hz ). Multiply this by a generous 20 entities a single match might have and that's about 15k-20k bytes per second.

Is this too much? What should I be aiming for? What data rates do games typically have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shawn Hargreaves wrote few slides for Xbox live gaming, concerning latencies, you can check the full presentation from [here](http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/MakingNetworkedGames.pdf)

> Bandwidth -
>   How much is available? Assume 64 kilobits (8 kilobytes) per second

0.5 Mbit/s ADSL has theoretical limit of 64kbs